# What techniques are there for preventing multiple submissions to a competition?

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter, captcha

**The Project**

We have a competition coded in PHP, with CodeIgniter. The form has validation on email addresses and mobile numbers. The page itself is hosted inside an iframe on a different domain (it's an agency-client relationship).

**The Problem**

We get users with 1000s of entries. We know they are fake because:

1. They use the same mobile number - assumedly they figure out a mobile number that passes the validation and then use that every time.
2. The email addresses are all on weird domains, with some of the domains repeated multiple times.

However, the IP addresses are unique, the entries are spread over a few days, the domains themselves have MX records, the user-agents look normal.

The client doesn't want to do anything which could result in fewer entries.

**The Question**

What are the pros and cons of methods like Captcha? What UI and code patterns have you used that worked?

One method I read is to allow entries that are suspicious, so that spammers entries are accepted, but their data has a 'suspicious' flag against it, which is then checked manually. What data can I check to see whether it is suspicious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CONS of CAPTCHA:

1. Users hate it, and it can be frustrating when implemented poorly (failed captcha resets other form fields for instance).
2. Can be difficult for legit users to complete when the letters are hard to read.
3. Doesn't always work. Someone just [scammed Ticketmaster by beating ReCAPTCHA](http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2010/11/wiseguys-plead-guilty/) a few months ago for instance*.
4. Ugly, more code to implement, and it passes the burden or responsibility from you to the users. PROVE YOU ARE HUMAN is not what I want to see when sending a form, very insulting.

@Nick's got the right idea, use text/email validation. IP checking can be OK sometimes, but as you said, you're getting unique IPs with the same mobile number, so it's not reliable.

There are lots of great posts here regarding CAPTCHA alternatives, definitely worth a read if you plan on employing it. You'll probably have to find a balance between making it easy for the user (encouraging submissions) and front end security techniques.

Why though, can't you simply disregard duplicate mobile numbers or phome number + IP combination? Just because they can can submit multiple times doesn't mean you have to accept it. If it is a human, let them think they are sending in multiple votes :)

> *<sub>Ticketmaster used various means
>   to try to thwart Wiseguy’s operation,
>   at one point switching to a service
>   called reCaptcha, which is also used
>   by Facebook. It’s a third-party
>   Captcha that feeds a Captcha challenge
>   to a site’s visitors. When a customer
>   tries to purchase tickets,
>   Ticketmaster’s network sends a unique
>   code to reCaptcha, which then
>   transmits a Captcha challenge to the
>   customer.</sub>
>
> <sub>But the defendants allegedly were
>   able to thwart this, as well. They
>   wrote a script that impersonated users
>   trying to access Facebook, and
>   downloaded hundreds of thousands of
>   possible Captcha challenges from
>   reCaptcha, prosecutors maintained.
>   They identified the file ID of each
>   Captcha challenge and created a
>   database of Captcha “answers” to
>   correspond to each ID. The bot would
>   then identify the file ID of a
>   challenge at Ticketmaster and feed
>   back the corresponding answer. The bot
>   also mimicked human behavior by
>   occasionally making mistakes in typing
>   the answer, authorities said.</sub>

Comment: The disregarding option is one I'm leaning towards at the moment - like you say, it then puts the responsibility back on me the developer, rather than the users. It also doesn't tell spammers that we're disregarding the entry, so there is no feedback with which to learn how to beat the form.

Comment: Email/text message confirmation validation is the only sure-fire way, but it's more work for the user and probably will result in slightly less submissions, plus more work for you :) Actually, this still doesn't solve the issue of humans submitting multiple times, as they can confirm multiple times. I honestly think the last paragraph in my answer is what I would do, seems like the best way. You can even choose whether or not you want to show an error or false success message.

Comment: 1 issue I just thought of but maybe it's splitting hairs: If someone uses my phone number for a spam submission, then I won't be able to send a "legit" submission. If this is an issue, you will definitely need to validation by confirmation.

Comment: Yes, I think I'll go with the post-validation work combined with some kind of not too difficult captcha if the user has JavaScript disabled. I like the idea of validating somehow with mobile number but there is the issue you mentioned above to contend with. Thanks for your help (@everyone).

Comment: @Blowski: I appreciate the acceptance, but you only asked this an hour ago, don't you want to leave it open so more people will contribute? I think this is a great question and marking it as resolved so early means that it will get less attention. What if some expert decides to drop by? :)

Comment: @Blowski: What you did is actually pretty "normal", but by no means is it proper IMO. There is a bad tendency with SO users to try to act fast in both posting and accepting which leads to poor quality content. Just vote up the stuff you like, vote down the really bad stuff, and if you have lots of good answers after 24-48hrs then pick the one *that helped you the most*. It's important to note that your question is going to be read by others in the future and its in everyone's best interest (including yours and mine) to get a wide array of opinions and solutions.

Comment: And remember: First is not the same as best!

Answer (score 2):

Some methods you could use:

- **Captcha**: Stops bots submitting the form
- **Email Validation**: Send them an email with a unique link to *activate* their competition entry.  Stops invalid email addresses.
- **Mobile Number Validation**: Send them a text message with an *activation code*.  Stops invalid phone numbers.

In my opinion your approach should not be to prevent submission of entries but to require a level of validation on the details entered.

Comment: Surely it's not difficult to automate the process of clicking on the email address? We're already validating that the domain has an MX record. I agree that mobile number validation would be much harder to beat.

Comment: It's not the automation of the clicking of the email account that I was worried about, it was the validity of the email address and simply ensuring that people aren't entering garbage email addresses just to find an unique combination.

Answer (score 0):

Captcha is perfect in spam protection while confusing people very often.

But there is a workaround - You can use JavaScript to hide the captcha for real users (using browsers with JavaScript turned ON) while it will always be "visible" for spam bots (that do not have JS). It's quite simple - just by using of JS You set the div where the captcha is held to display:none, and create a hidden input with value containing that from captcha image...

Strongest approach may be the email validation - but then it means sometimes the rwritting of application. If user submit his reply You register it as not active and send him a validation email to the email address provided. If it is valid, after clicking on the link he will validate his email answer and You can turn his reply to status active...

Also a good workaround for users to prevent the re-submitting of forms on refresh is to redirect users to that same page after the form is submitted and processed... Yes, it takes a second or two longer to view the result, but it's much safer...

Comment: That was one of my thoughts. I have used Selenium RC to get round captcha while testing, so I know that it's not impossible. In fact, if I can do it, it must be fairly easy.

Comment: @Charliepiga: I don't understand Your thought... And don't understand why You don't understood me. We use this implementation of captcha in all of our projects - people are not annoyed by captcha (when JS turned ON), while with JS turned OFF the captcha is there... JS takes the captcha value from PHP and puts it in the input's value and then hide all the captcha div... A SPAM bot is just a script (that cannot use JS), so the input with captcha is present but with empty value so after submitting You are not annoyed by SPAM... Clear now?

Comment: "You can use JavaScript to hide the captcha for real users (using browsers with JavaScript turned ON) while it will always be 'visible' for spam bots (that do not have JS)" - This is the part I don't get. Are you saying that since all bots don't have JS enabled you should not show captcha users having JS enabled?

Comment: Congrats, You get it right. Developers should understand that captcha is annoying for users, sometimes it is so hard to read and You can end up with trying to submit the form for an hour because of bad captcha... So very good approach on this (when convinced to use captcha anyway) is to HIDE captcha element (while still present somewhere behind) for REAL users with REAL browsers and ofc. with JS turned ON...